# Polish spaces without the completeness requirement?

Tags: general-topology

Sorry to bother you with such a simple question, but I was wondering if a topological space that satisfies all the properties of a Polish space but without the completeness property has an established name other than simply "separable and metrizable".

Thanks in advance

Comment: In short, I don't think so.

Comment: @StevenClontz Ok, thank you very much !